# How to add Apex Class Access to permission set programmatically

Tags: apex, permission-sets

Is there any chance to add Apex Class Access to a permission set programmatically?
E.g. the following code allows [adding field permissions to the perm set](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/340053/how-to-change-field-permissions-in-a-permission-set-or-profile-programmatically).

```
insert new FieldPermissions(
        ParentId = '0PSXXXXXXXXXXXX', // perm set id
        SobjectType = SObjectType.Account.getName(), 
        Field = Account.Type.getDescribe().getName(),
        PermissionsRead = true,
        PermissionsEdit = false,  
);
```

Does anyone know how to do the same with Apex Classes?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to be done in the same way as with `FieldPermissions`, but you need to use [`SetupEntityAccess`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_SetupEntityAccess.htm) object instead:

```
insert new SetupEntityAccess(
        ParentId = '0PS...', // PermissionSet ID
        SetupEntityId = '01p...' // ApexClass ID
);
```

Comment: Works great, thanks!