# How to grant apex class access to profile programmatically

Tags: apex, profile

Is there a way to grant apex class access to a profile programmatically?

There is an [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/360879/how-to-add-apex-class-access-to-permission-set-programmatically) on how to grant access to permission set, how to do the same but with profiles?

Something like this:

```
  // the following doesn't work
  insert new SetupEntityAccess(
        ParentId = '0PS...', // Profile Id
        SetupEntityId = '01p...' // ApexClass Id
  );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per Salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_setupentityaccess.htm).

`ParentId` only takes Permission Set Ids.

Its better to create a permission set and get that permission set added to user using `PermissionSetAssignment`

Comment: Agree, but I'm looking for a method to add the access to profile. Do you know the way to do so?)

Comment: Profile can only be modified via Metadata api, not via Apex directly.  https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found the answer to my question :)
It's possible to add apex class access via Metadata API

```
makeRequest();

/* SCRIPT */
final static String API_VERSION = '58';
public String generateEnvelope() {
    return '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n' +
            '<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">\n' +
            '    <env:Header>\n' +
            '        <SessionHeader xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">\n' +
            '            <sessionId>' + UserInfo.getSessionId() + '</sessionId>\n' +
            '        </SessionHeader>\n' +
            '    </env:Header>\n' +
            '    <env:Body>\n' +
            '        <updateMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">\n' +
            '            <metadata xsi:type="Profile">\n' +
            '                <fullName>Sales</fullName>\n' +
            '                <custom>true</custom>\n' +
            '                <classAccesses>\n' +
            '                    <apexClass>AccountTriggerHandler</apexClass>\n' +
            '                    <enabled>true</enabled>\n' +
            '                </classAccesses>\n' +
            '            </metadata>\n' +
            '        </updateMetadata>\n' +
            '    </env:Body>\n' +
            '</env:Envelope> ';
}

public void makeRequest() {
    String endpoint = Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/Soap/m/' + API_VERSION + '/';
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('SOAPAction', 'update');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    String body = generateEnvelope();
    System.debug(body);
    req.setBody(body);
    HttpResponse response = new Http().send(req);
    System.debug('response status code: ' + response.getStatusCode());
    System.debug('response: ' + response.getBody());
}
```

Where

- <fullName>Sales</fullName> - profile name
- <apexClass>AccountTriggerHandler</apexClass> - name of the apex class
- <enabled>true</enabled> true of false

Answer (score 0):

You can try this!

```
List<ApexClass> clList = [select id from apexclass where name ='Class1' or name='Class2'];
List<SetupEntityAccess > entityList = new List<SetupEntityAccess>();
List<PermissionSet> ps = [ select id,name,Profile.name from PermissionSet 
                          where IsOwnedByProfile = true and 
                          profile.name='Integrations'];
for (PermissionSet p:ps) { 
    for(ApexClass cl: clList){
        entityList.add( new SetupEntityAccess(
            ParentId = p.Id, //permissionSetId of profile
            SetupEntityId = cl.Id //classid
        ));    
    }
}
Database.insert(entityList, false);
```